# Creating a log in form

Tags: php, html, mysql, authentication, mysqli

I'm in the early stages of creating a log in form using php.

This is the code I've done so far. I'm using a tutorial which uses the mysql function. However I need to use my_sqli. I think this might be where I'm having problems. At the moment when I click on the submit button it just refreshes the page, I need it to display 'OK'.

This is being included on another page so it has other includes like my database connection on there. These are all fine and in working order.

```html
<?php

if (isset($_POST['email'])&&isset($_POST['password'])) {
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];

 $password_hash = md5($password);

 if (!empty($email)&&!empty($password)) {
  
  $query = "SELECT 'userID' FROM registeredusers WHERE email='$email' AND  password='$password_hash'";
  if ($query_run = mysqli_query($query)) {
   $query_run_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query_run);
    if ($query_run_rows==0) {
     echo 'Invalid email or password.';
    } else {
     echo 'OK.';
    }

  }

 } else {
  echo 'Please enter email and password';
 }
}

?>

     <form action="<?php echo $current_file ?>" method="POST">
     <p>Email: <input type="email" name="email"></p> 
     <p>Password: <input type="password" name="password"></p>
     <input type="submit" value="Log In">
     </form>
```

Comment: Start by learning what table and column identifiers are http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html  you will then figure out where you went wrong.

Comment: @Fred-ii- that has nothing to do with his issue.

Comment: @JoeSwindell I doubt that very much, not by wrapping column names in quotes. You're telling me that this is valid? `SELECT 'userID'`

Comment: While not the desired results, It is in fact valid SQL and will return results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a couple things you can change so far.

mysqli_query() requires 2 parameters and optional third.

```
mysqli_query(connection,query) <-- Probably 99% using this.

mysqli_query(connection,query, resultmode)
```

An example might be:

```
$dbc = defined_elsewhere_database_connection;
$q = "SELECT 'userID' FROM registeredusers WHERE email='$email' AND  password='$password_hash'";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
```

Now to process results:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($r) ===1) {
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   validate $row with whatever;
} else {
   echo 'invalid password/email';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is not basically running okay.

You should have 2 parameter for mysqli_query.First parameter is to connect to database and second parameter is the query itself.So,just do this if you are in localhost server

```
$connect=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','database_name');

$query = "SELECT userID FROM registeredusers WHERE email='$email' AND  password='$password_hash'";
if ($query_run = mysqli_query($connect,$query)) {
................................
...............................


}
```

This should work

Comment: Thats got it! I had it like that before but took on the parameter that connects to my db! Can't believe I didn't think to try it with it in like I previously had it. Thanks for the help!